# Search and Replace with random number generation

Tags: python, vim

I have a configuration file that defines a collection of objects like this:

```
[object 1]
param1 = 1
param2 = 2
rate = 0.01
```

For testing purposes, I want to randomize the value of each `rate` parameter. Since my development environment already is vim, I want to find a regex that can search for the rate parameter and replace it with a random value. I know vim isn't good with random number generation but I also know you can use python to help define custom functions. However, any functions I create output the result into the buffer, not the search/replace string.

I have a function like:

```
function! Random()
: python << EOF
: import numpy as np
: print np.random.uniform(0.25,1)
: EOF
: endfunction
```

and my regex looks like:

```
:s/rate = \d\.\d*/\=Random()
```

I know this would replace the entire line with a random number, but that's something easy I can fix later. The issue is that the output of Random() goes into the message area, not the buffer. How do I correct this?

Comment: Why you want to update the file with the randomly generated number? Why not generating and using the number as the part of your program?

Comment: unfortunately, I dont have access to that part of the code. My only interface is with these config files.

Answer (score 3):

I found that the return value of a vim function can be accessed through the vim.command() function in python.

I modified my function as follows:

```
function! Random()
: python << EOF
: import vim
: import numpy as np
: vim.command("return {0}".format(np.random.uniform(0.25,1)))
: EOF
: endfunction
```

this produced the results I was looking for